# Office 365 SharePoint Online 2013 REST with SoapUI

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, rest

Im trying to run Office 365 SharePoint Online REST API calls. I get an error message:

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.</m:message>
</m:error>
```

- As authentication I tried different options:Global Http Settings / Preemptive / NTLM/Kerberos; obviously none of them work. Anyone can give me advice as what I'm doing wrong?
- Anyone succeeded running REST API calls on SharePoint Online 2013?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

The error message that I am getting

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5    
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
X-Forms_Based_Auth_Required: https://SITEURL.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=/_layouts/15/error.aspx&Source=%2f_vti_bin%2flists.asmx
X-Forms_Based_Auth_Return_Url: https://SITEURL.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/error.aspx
X-MSDAVEXT_Error: 917656;     
Access+denied.+Before+opening+files+in+this+location%2c+you+must+first+browse+to+the+web+site+and+select+the+option+to+login+automatically.
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
SPRequestGuid: 5ad8999c-09cc-1018-5b28-e0ba7fe53991
request-id: 5ad8999c-09cc-1018-5b28-e0ba7fe53991
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
SPRequestDuration: 28
SPIisLatency: 0
X-IDCRL_AUTH_PARAMS_V1: IDCRL Type="BPOSIDCRL",         
EndPoint="/sites/SUBSITEURL/_vti_bin/idcrl.svc/", RootDomain="sharepoint.com", Policy="MBI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.2916
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
P3P: CP="ALL IEE DSP COR ADG CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PDF TAS TELo OUR SAMo CNT CEE INT NAV ONL PWW PRE PUR UNI"
Date: Wed, 11 Jun 2014 14:33:12 GMT
Content-Length: 13

403 FORBIDDEN
```

Comment: Can someone please add a tag for SOAPUI.

Comment: Is SoapUI covered here?

Comment: not sure where could post this query, as it had to do with SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 2):

Look at http://paulryan.com.au/2014/spo-remote-authentication-rest/
It works for me (if I get you right). Just ignore stuff about digest - put mentioned 2 cookies into your header as `Cookie:c1;c2` where `c1` and `c2` are authentication cookies (ones starting from `FedAuth=` and `rtFa=`).

Answer (score 1):

The same issue has been reported on SoupUI forums, but there is no solution yet. The same issue is there in On-premise mode also. The issue lies in Authenticating the service.

There is workaround listed on there [forum](https://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=22368&p=50933&sid=2223e405694eb65ba9a4ddf9e3d3e1c6#p50933), You can check that.

Comment: I m looking to get SoapUI visit the Secure Token Webservice and get a session cookie. I haven't yet found out how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue using a header with some info about connection:

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36

Add new Header at SoapUI Request, name it User-Agent, and the value is from the word Mozilla/5.0 to the end.

Grettings